# pages are displaying plain text instead of html

Tags: apache, movabletype

I am hosting multiple sites on the same server and using a http-vhosts file to specify virtual host info for them. It is working great. The problem is I changed in Movable Type the way entries are created. I want them to not have file extension. So it is currently domain.com/entry/15 instead of domain.com/entry/15.html. Because I took out the .html I'm assuming apache doesn't know what to do so it is spitting out the page as plain text. How can I fix this? I added in a virtualhost block:

```
DefaultType text/html
```

I also added that in the httpd.conf hoping it would fix it globally for all my sites. I restarted apache and still the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that this is a content negotiation problem?  In a few cases I've seen Apache try to determine what sort of file is being requested by looking at the first few bytes of the file being served.

I have seen problems like this be solved by commenting out mod_negotiation in http.conf and restarting.  See the [mod_negotiation documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the same issue by disbabling Magic Mime in httpd.conf (some files would display as html and some as text for no apparent reason).

edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment the lines for the Mime Magic Module:

```
MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
```

Restart Apache and clear your browser cache

[source](http://realtechtalk.com/HTML_files_in_Apache_still_displaying_as_raw_text_even_with_DefaultType_ForceType_etc-1752-articles)

Answer (score 0):

That seems correct. Care to share one link, or the HTTP headers that are returned for one of those pages? P.S. as well as the whole Apache config block where you placed that directive, for context?

Answer (score 0):

if u create a .htaccess in ur site's root dir,and the .htaccess's content is:
DefaultType text/html
then the issue is fixed imm.