# javascript won't execute - only displays code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a javascript file in my browser but the code is displayed and not actually executed. I'm using firefox and I made sure javascript is enabled. I tried using a .js extension and .shtml and both just display the code. The file is located in my apache htdocs folder and it's version 2.2.

I'm trying to run this hello world code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="hello"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the javascript

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hello world';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can we see your javascript code?

Comment: Which code is displayed, the HTML or the js code? You will need to change its MIME-type. If HTML is not parsed as HTML, the script of course won't be executed.

Comment: @tomasz this is the code I'm referencing http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/First-JavaScript-Example.htm

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for a legitimate question?

Comment: Probably because your question isn't very clear. What code is displaying in your browser? Are you seeing the HTML or something else?

Comment: It's just showing the HTML in the browser.

Comment: If you open the html file directly in your browser without using any web server, does it work? For example, open your browser, go to File > Open, and find the html file and open it. What happens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pages are displaying plain text instead of html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142117/pages-are-displaying-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Comment: i would open a traffic analyzer such as fiddler and check that your javascript file is actually being found and not a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body  onload="onload1()">
        <p id="hello"></p>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**helloworld.js**

```
        function onload1(){
         document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hello world';
        }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I also uninstalled and re-installed apache so that could have been the case too. Regardless, thanks for your help.

Comment: Apache sounds more likely to have been the issue here. Glad you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You have no element with the ID of `ex`.

With the HTML you've shown, your line should be:

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'hello world';
```

See now that `<p>` tag has the `id="hello"` -- how would a call to `getElementById('ex')` be able to find that?

---

**EDIT**

Working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uz8b/)

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code but it's still just displaying the HTML and not executing.

Comment: Describe "displaying" the HTML?  Also, you will see nothing 'execute' -- the instant your page loads, it'll run that javascript command and insert those characters into the DOM. I've updated my answer with a JSFiddle example that shows you that it does work.

Comment: It displays the contents of the document. It doesn't do anything other than show the HTML that's in the code box above.

Comment: @user1104854 as in you're seeing the actual HTML as printed above?  You've got a server configuration problem as well then.

Comment: I re-installed apache and it works. I was writing PHP earlier and it was display just fine, but I guess it was a server issue.

Answer (score -1):

Save the above code as .htm or .html. Your server is probably not configured to use SSI (.shtml extension).

You said you saved it as .js and as .shtml, this is probably where you have gone wrong. .js files will not display properly when opened directly by the browser, as the browser is not intended for displaying JavaScipt, thus you must use a file type that is intended for HTML. The .shtml extension is for HTML, however it is only used with servers using SSI (Server Side Includes), so if the server does not use SSI it will not work.

Usually you will see code when the mime type is wrong. The mime type is how the server tells the browser what kind of file it is sending http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type. The server sends the mime type, which it determines by looking a the files extension, or in some cases certain parts of the file (and server side code can adjust the mime type as well). The server will give files with the .htm and .html extension the HTML mime type, but .js will not have that type. The .shtml file will only be given the HTML mime type if the server uses SSI. So when the browser gets those files it will intemperate them as plain text. This is why you see the code.

So either change the extension to .htm or .html, or enable SSI on the server (or ensure it is configured to work in that directory).

As a side note, your JS will not do anything as there is no element with the ID 'ex', however that should not produce the problem of seeing code. It will however give you trouble down the line.

Comment: I corrected the 'ex' ID. What exactly is the mime type? Sorry, but I'm new to javascript.

Comment: @Zeel answers are not for conjecture.  If you need more information, post a comment on the original question.  Only provide solid factual information in answers.

Comment: @tkone It was an answer, but I see how it was a little poor at expressing the point. Completely reworked it + added information/explanation.

Comment: Still wrong though. You can name a file with an shtml extension, include no ssi directives, and still have the page render perfectly fine in a browser.

Comment: That is not what I said. "The .shtml extension is for HTML, however it is only used with servers using SSI (Server Side Includes), so if the server does not use SSI it will not work." the server is what is in question, if it is not configured for using SSI it may send the wrong mime type, because it may not understand what .shtml is. My answer has no major flaws.

Comment: In fact, given other information in comments on other answers it very much does sound as if the server was at fault. He said he was using PHP and it worked fine, and after server re-install it worked. Thus it almost certainly was a server problem, assigning the wrong mime type to the .shtml file.