# Twig is not rendered on web browser, it shows plain html code

Tags: php, apache, symfony, twig, apache2

I have just established Symfony 3.3(standard edition) on apache 2.4 mysql php 7.1 environment. I have arranged configurations of vhost and host files.however when I run my localhost, instead of seeing landing page, I just see html code of index.html.twig

my apache vhosts configuration is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName selfdev.dev
    ServerAlias selfdev.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/'username'/Sites/selfdev/web"
    <Directory "/Users/'username'/Sites/selfdev/web">
              AllowOverride All
              Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
              Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/selfdev.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/selfdev.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

what shall I do to see in a proper rendered page form?[image]

[image]

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="welcome">
                <h1><span>Welcome to</span> Symfony {{ constant('Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel::VERSION') }}</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="status">
                <p>
                    <svg id="icon-status" width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#759E1A"/></svg>

                    Your application is now ready. You can start working on it at:
                    <code>{{ base_dir }}</code>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="next">
                <h2>What's next?</h2>
                <p>
                    <svg id="icon-book" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-12.5 9 64 64" enable-background="new -12.5 9 64 64" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path fill="#AAA" d="M6.8,40.8c2.4,0.8,4.5-0.7,4.9-2.5c0.2-1.2-0.3-2.1-1.3-3.2l-0.8-0.8c-0.4-0.5-0.6-1.3-0.2-1.9
                            c0.4-0.5,0.9-0.8,1.8-0.5c1.3,0.4,1.9,1.3,2.9,2.2c-0.4,1.4-0.7,2.9-0.9,4.2l-0.2,1c-0.7,4-1.3,6.2-2.7,7.5
                            c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.6c-0.3,0-0.4-0.3-0.4-0.3c0-0.3,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.3,0.4-0.8c0-0.7-0.6-1.3-1.3-1.3
                            c-0.6,0-1.4,0.6-1.4,1.7s1,1.9,2.4,1.8c0.8,0,2.5-0.3,4.2-2.5c2-2.5,2.5-5.4,2.9-7.4l0.5-2.8c0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.1
                            c2.4,0.1,3.7-1.3,3.7-2.3c0-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.9-1.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.3-1,0.8c-0.1,0.6,0.8,1.1,0.1,1.5c-0.5,0.3-1.4,0.6-2.7,0.4l0.3-1.3
                            c0.5-2.6,1-5.7,3.2-5.8c0.2,0,0.8,0,0.8,0.4c0,0.2,0,0.2-0.2,0.5c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.2,0.7c0,0.7,0.5,1.1,1.2,1.1
                            c0.9,0,1.2-1,1.2-1.4c0-1.2-1.2-1.8-2.6-1.8c-1.5,0.1-2.8,0.9-3.7,2.1c-1.1,1.3-1.8,2.9-2.3,4.5c-0.9-0.8-1.6-1.8-3.1-2.3
                            c-1.1-0.7-2.3-0.5-3.4,0.3c-0.5,0.4-0.8,1-1,1.6c-0.4,1.5,0.4,2.9,0.8,3.4l0.9,1c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.8,0.4,1.5c-0.3,0.8-1.2,1.3-2.1,1
                            c-0.4-0.2-1-0.5-0.9-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5s0.1-0.3,0.1-0.3c0.2-0.6-0.1-1.4-0.7-1.6c-0.6-0.2-1.2,0-1.3,0.8
                            C4.3,38.4,4.7,40,6.8,40.8z M46.1,20.9c0-4.2-3.2-7.5-7.1-7.5h-3.8C34.8,10.8,32.7,9,30.2,9L-2.3,9.1c-2.8,0.1-4.9,2.4-4.9,5.4
                            L-7,58.6c0,4.8,8.1,13.9,11.6,14.1l34.7-0.1c3.9,0,7-3.4,7-7.6L46.1,20.9z M-0.3,36.4c0-8.6,6.5-15.6,14.5-15.6
                            c8,0,14.5,7,14.5,15.6S22.1,52,14.2,52C6.1,52-0.3,45-0.3,36.4z M42.1,65.1c0,1.8-1.5,3.1-3.1,3.1H4.6c-0.7,0-3-1.8-4.5-4.4h30.4
                            c2.8,0,5-2.4,5-5.4V17.9h3.7c1.6,0,2.9,1.4,2.9,3.1V65.1L42.1,65.1z"/>
                    </svg>

                    Read the documentation to learn
                    <a href="http://symfony.com/doc/{{ constant('Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel::VERSION')[:3] }}/page_creation.html">
                        How to create your first page in Symfony
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<style>
    body { background: #F5F5F5; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
    h1, h2 { line-height: 1.2; margin: 0 0 .5em; }
    h1 { font-size: 36px; }
    h2 { font-size: 21px; margin-bottom: 1em; }
    p { margin: 0 0 1em 0; }
    a { color: #0000F0; }
    a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
    code { background: #F5F5F5; max-width: 100px; padding: 2px 6px; word-wrap: break-word; }
    #wrapper { background: #FFF; margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; }
    #container { padding: 2em; }
    #welcome, #status { margin-bottom: 2em; }
    #welcome h1 span { display: block; font-size: 75%; }
    #icon-status, #icon-book { float: left; height: 64px; margin-right: 1em; margin-top: -4px; width: 64px; }
    #icon-book { display: none; }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        #wrapper { width: 80%; margin: 2em auto; }
        #icon-book { display: inline-block; }
        #status a, #next a { display: block; }

        @-webkit-keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
        @keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
        .sf-toolbar { opacity: 0; -webkit-animation: fade-in 1s .2s forwards; animation: fade-in 1s .2s forwards;}
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: Is this really the raw template? I can't see any format codes.

Comment: Post your apache configuration. Are you using `mod_negotiation` ? Also, post the HTTP headers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for your welcome. I didn't copy pasted since I didn't change anything on page html. So that means it is the default index.html.twig that you can find anywhere.
However if you want to see exactly that default html, I can give that too.

Comment: Check your browser settings or try with a different browser.  You are not looking at the twig file.  You are in fact looking at the properly rendered html. For some reason your browser is showing you the raw html instead of a regular rendered page.

Comment: @gobo Restart Apache!

Comment: The default template looks [like this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/app/Resources/views/admin/blog/index.html.twig), i.e., with stuff like `<h1>{{ 'title.post_list'|trans }}</h1>` instead of `<h1><span>Welcome to </span> Symfony 3.3.0</h1>`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have edited post with index.html.twig which is the default one

Comment: @Cerad I have the same result with safari

Comment: @ccKep I have checked apache configuration and mod_negotiation is disabled. I have updated post with HTTP headers if you would like to check

Comment: @aendeerei I have done that zbillion times dude!

Comment: No, seriously, your Twig template **is rendered**. Look carefully! However, something's telling the browser it's supposed to be **JSON** instead of **HTML**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pages are displaying plain text instead of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142117/pages-are-displaying-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Comment: Try using bin/console server:start and see what happens.  That will at least isolate the problem to either Apache configuration or Symfony.

Comment: Can you also post the code of the controller and the list of bundles you use (do you use FOSRestBundle for instance)?

Comment: @KévinDunglas I use FOSRestBundle, JMSSerializerBundle, NelmioCorsBundle

Comment: Well you could have led with that.  You have something mis-configured causing all responses to get the text/json header.  Dig into the docs or maybe start a fresh project and go step by step.

Comment: @Cerad I think problem is on Content-Type:application/json of Response header. How can I change this ? through apache? or through my code?

Comment: You are correct that the problem is the content-type and that it is a Symfony issue.  I can't tell you how to fix it but I suspect the culprit is the way you configured the FOSRestBundle.  Beyond that you really just need to spend some time learning the basics and reading the docs.

Comment: Can you paste your FOSRestBundle configuration, the problem is probably there.

Answer (score 0):

i caused by fosRestBundle
add to your priorities "html" to tell him to support

```
    fos_rest:
  view:
    formats: { json: true, xml: false, rss: false }
    view_response_listener: true
  body_converter:
    enabled: true
    validate: true
    validation_errors_argument: violations
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: "^/", priorities: ["json", "html"], fallback_format: "json" }
```