# folder in apache is not interpreting html

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with a folder in apache, some folders show correctly the html code but some other shows me the code, i dont want to see the code, any file that i create in that folder its shows me the code, as you can see in the next example:

https://www.midominio.net/rsarchivos/gabriel.html

in any other folder i can see the code right, for example:

https://www.midominio.net/admin/gabriel.html

Its only html code as you can see on this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hola Mundo
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hola Mundo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

No other libraries are called in this file or any other tag. Any advice to fix that?

Comment: check permissions and owners on folders and files

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142117/pages-are-displaying-plain-text-instead-of-html

Comment: @Luis, is this html being returned by code from the server?  The one that is showing the html is wrapped in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Im not calling this tags on my code, but the pre tags works to force the code to show the blank spaces.

Comment: Maybe try removing them?  Don't know what you mean by blank spaces, maybe try `&nbsp; ` to insert space?

Comment: But how can i do that? im not writing that <pre> on my code... The code is just like you can see it in the post! how can even been called that <pre>?

Comment: Check to make sure that the path to /rsarchivos/gabriel.html is correct.  If I paste the code in your post into your site it works as expected.

Comment: I checked about the permision and files that are working well have the same permissions

Comment: Yeah the path is correct, i only copy and pasted the url

Comment: Kamil is not the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the problem was that i had an .htaccess file saved and hidden in the directories that were affected. I just delete that file and problem solved!

Thanks to the community for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check apache virtual host or main config:

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

<Directory /var/www/your-project/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Add .html DirectoryIndex to render html in subfolder.

Comment: Ill try that and ill let you know the results!

Comment: The problem is that this tag "<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">&lt;p&gt;Hola Mundo&lt;/p&gt;

</pre>" is "added" to all files in that directory but can be only see it inspecting the file. Is not added in the file inself. That code is affecting all my files in that directory.